# concatenate a function with string and execute it

Tags: bash, shell, sh

> I wanna concatenate a command specified in a function with string and execute it after.
>   I will simplify my need with an exemple to execute "ls -l -a"

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "specify command"
read command                                 # ls

echo -e "specify argument"
read arg                                     # -l

test () {
$command $arg
}

eval 'test -a'
```

> Except that

Comment: You're looking for `eval`. Use with care

Comment: not a good idea to define a function test because it's the `[` shell builtin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array, like this:

```
args=()

read -r command
args+=( "$command" )

read -r arg
args+=( "$arg" )

"${args[@]}" -a
```

If you want a function, then you could do this:

```
run_with_extra_switch () {
    "$@" -a
}

run_with_extra_switch "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: Fine !! I have used this the array method and it was working !!  Thank you

Comment: @AnasSlim Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I could not vote but I specified the best answer. Thank you for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "specify command"
read command                                 # ls

echo -e "specify argument"
read arg                                     # -l

# using variable
fun1 () {
    line="$command $arg"
}

# call the function
fun1
# parameter expansion will expand to the command and execute
$line

# or using stdout (overhead)
fun2 () {
    echo "$command $arg"
}
# process expansion will execute function in sub-shell and output will be expanded to a command and executed
$(fun2)
```

It will work for the given question however to understand how it works look at shell expansion and attention must be payed to execute arbitrary commands.

Before to execute the command, it can be prepended by `printf '<%s>\n'` for example to show what will be executed.